# Is there a way to show only specific file extensions?

Tags: windows-7, file-extension

Call me crazy, but I'm *sure* I remember this capability existing in previous versions of Windows.  In Windows 7, we can have file extensions Off... or On.  Pick one.  Is there some obscure switch buried in the registry to have Explorer show *specific* extensions, but leave the rest hidden?

In my case, I'd like to always show extensions for text files (*.txt, *.csv, *.tdt), because I frequently have to handle flat files which may come in with a .txt extension where I need it to be .csv, for example.  I'd rather not have extensions on all the time, it's just clutter for almost all files.

Comment: I recall the setting I toggle on all fresh Windows installs, is titled "Show known file type extensions" - so perhaps you can accomplish your means through editing the extension/application association list thingy. Though that sounds like a horrible solution - hence the comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I believe that if you disassociate the extension with a program then it will show the file extension for only that file.

Comment: obscure switch in registry "NeverShowExt" , works opposite of your desired intent. making the files of that extention type "superHidden"
No more info provided here, use web search. it will NOT do what you want, it is just one of the registry items.

Comment: @Psycogeek: `AlwaysShowExt` must be even more obscure, then? (It exists.)

Comment: You have to have MI5 clearance to use it though :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the Registry Editor, navigate to `HKCR` (although `HKCU\Software\Classes` would be a better location, but most are lazy). For every file type, create a zero-length string value named `AlwaysShowExt`.

For example, if you have `.txt`:

1. Navigate to the subkey for the extension – `HKCR\.txt` – and note the data stored in the "`(Default)`" value – it usually says `txtfile`.
2. Navigate to the file type subkey `HKCR\txtfile`, right-click the value list, choose *New → String value*, and name the new value `AlwaysShowExt`.

Not all extensions have separate subkeys for file types – sometimes all information is kept directly under `HKCR\.myext`. In such cases, `AlwaysShowExt` goes directly to the extension subkey as well.

---

It is *very* likely that there are dedicated programs for editing file types, possibly with support for `AlwaysShowExt` and other flags. I don't know any to recommend, though.

Comment: Groovy, that did it!  Well, *almost*.  Adding that tag to `HKCR\txtfile` and `HKCR\tdt_auto_file` worked for .txt, .log, and .tdt extensions, but adding it to `HKCR\Excel.CSV`, `HKCR\.csv`, and `HKCR\.csv\Excel.CSV` has not changed the behavior for .csv files.  Is there an extra step here?

Comment: FYI - Restart Explorer.exe for changes to take effect.