# Windows - don't hide file extensions of certain types

Tags: windows, file-extension

I want to hide all file extensions except for certain extensions/types. Is this possible?

I don't like the clutter of file extensions but as a developer I find it helpful to know the extensions of some types, like .htm vs. .html, and sometimes I change the extensions of certain types, like .apk to .zip. I want to avoid having to toggle the "Hide extensions for known file types" setting in the Folder Options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to show only specific file extensions?](http://superuser.com/questions/341042/is-there-a-way-to-show-only-specific-file-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

In all the years of PC usage, I'd like this idea.  But, there is no option to hide selected extensions.  You can "show all" in the folder options, as you mentioned.

Comment: See and31415's comment above.