# How to show only specific file extensions?

Tags: windows-10, file-management

I want to have a folder where I can see all the .pdf files that I have on several different folders.

You may have different files on this folder but when you open it it will only show you a specific file extension.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Maybe the same with http://superuser.com/questions/341042/is-there-a-way-to-show-only-specific-file-extensions

Comment: It sounds like you want to seach for a file (*.pdf) and save that search. [Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/save-a-search) is a Microsoft description on how to do that. Not sure if that's what you're looking for though...

Answer (score 3):

### How to show one extension

Yes, this is possible with a Registry Tweak ([explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/341042/is-there-a-way-to-show-only-specific-file-extensions)). I just tested this with **Windows 10** before recommending it, however, and wrote my own explanation below. Note: You cannot do this for only *one* folder, however.

1. Press <kbd>Win+R</kbd> and type `regedit`
2. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` then the extension you want. In your case:

[image]

3. Double click the `Default` value

[image]

4. Find the value from `Default` under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and add a new `String Value`

[image]

5. Name it as shown below

[image]

6. Restart `explorer.exe` and you're done

---

### How to show all extensions

Now lets look at how to *all* show extensions, if you decide you'd prefer it over the method above.

- Start searching for "Show or Hide File Extensions"

[image]

- Uncheck `Hide extensions for known file types`

[image]